# Is it possible to prevent console log for bat command in jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-cli

I have to prevent the console log in jenkinsfile for bat command. i.e I want to prevent some execution result from bat command

```
def test = bat(script: command, returnStdout: true).trim()
```

but it prints the command output in the bat pipeline.

```
[branch-name] Running batch script
[Pipeline] bat

Some output lines from bat command
```

Is it possible to prevent this command log in jenkins output?

Comment: `def test = bat(script: 'echo hello', returnStdout: true).trim()`

Does not print anything to me, can you give an example how to reproduce the error?

What version of  _workflow-durable-task-step_ do you use?

Comment: After I upgrade pipeline and all other plugins, it resolved.